# Aiogram Python. Как получить информацию введенную пользователём в боте telegram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно, чтобы бот пересылал ответ пользователя на сообщение бота определённому контакту, как это образовать? Библиотека aiogram, язык python

Comment: пожалуйста, ответьте кто нибудь(

Comment: [найдутся и дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baiogram%5D+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB)